Raspberry Pi Zero W UART, Bluetooth, and USB
I have a Raspberry Pi with Bluetooth using the /dev/ttyAMA0 and a UART using /dev/ttyS0. Is it also possible to use the USB as another UART? Are pins 14 and 15 tied to the USB as well?

Does this answer your question? How to enable both UART (ttyS0 and ttyAMA0) on Raspberry Pi 3b?

I would like ttyAMA0, ttyS0, and the USB port, but I am not sure if the ttyS0 is the same as the USB port

Your question is ambiguous. Do you have a USB serial dongle? How is it connected? If in Pi USB it will probably be /dev/ttyAMA0. /dev/ttyS0 is the mini UART on the SoC normally on GPIO 14, 15.

I want /dev/ttyAMA0 the bluetooth device, /dev/ttyS0, the minor UART, and somethng line /dev/ACM0 or /dev/USB0 in which the USB acts as another serial port

The USB is not tied to Pins 14 or 15. The USB becomes what it plugged to it. A card reader with a SD Card becomes a USB Disk. A Raspberry Pi Pico becomes a TTY Device (/dev/ttyACM0). As Milliways suggested, a USB Serial Dongle becomes a TTY device.
